# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. because of setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

There might be issue in `setFormData`, can someone please tell me what mistake i have done that causing  rendering in the code. also want to know if there is any mistake in storing image in a state.

Code summary:

1. I am adding image from input field, and this is taken care by `imageSelectedHandler`
2. I want to know is `imageUploadHandler` required? or even without using I will be able to submit the form along with the image?
3. I am also adding new input fields, everytime user clicks, add specification button. this is by addClick and removeClick handler
4. handleChange handler take care of indivisual Input Flield.

Please help someone.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormInput from "../Forminput/forminput";
import CustomButton from "../Custombutton/custombutton";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductUpload = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    sub_category: null,
    product_name: null,
    product_image: null,
    product_specs: [{ specification: "", specvalue: "" }],
  });

  const { sub_category, product_name, product_image, product_specs } = formData;

  const imageSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      product_image: event.target.files[0],
      sub_category: { ...prevState.sub_category },
      product_name: { ...prevState.product_name },
      product_specs: [
        ...prevState.product_specs,
        { specification: "", specvalue: "" },
      ],
    }));
  };

  const imageUploadHandler = () => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("product_image", product_image, product_image.name); //.name is Imp as name is property of file
  };
  const handleChange = (i, e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    product_specs[i] = { ...product_specs[i], [name]: value };
    setFormData({ product_specs }); //TO BE CHECKED
  };
  //to add extra input field
  const addClick = () => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      sub_category: { ...prevState.sub_category },
      product_image: { ...prevState.image },
      product_name: { ...prevState.product_name },
      product_specs: [
        ...prevState.product_specs,
        { specification: "", specvalue: "" },
      ],
    }));
  };
  //to remove extra input field
  const removeClick = (i) => {
    product_specs.splice(i, 1);
    setFormData((prevState) => {
      return {
        sub_category: { ...prevState.sub_category },
        product_image: { ...prevState.image },
        product_name: { ...prevState.product_name },
        product_specs: [
          ...prevState.product_specs,
          { specification: "", specvalue: "" },
        ],
      };
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newProduct = {
      sub_category,
      product_name,
      product_image,
      product_specs,
    };
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newProduct);
      const res = await axios.post("/api/product", body, config);
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };
  const createUI = () => {
    return product_specs.map((el, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="inputgroup">
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="specification"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={el.specification}
          label="specification"
          required
          customwidth="300px"
        ></FormInput>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="specvalue"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={el.specvalue}
          label="specification values seperated by quomas"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        <CustomButton
          onClick={removeClick(i)}
          type="button"
          value="remove"
          style={{ margin: "12px" }}
        >
          Remove
        </CustomButton>
      </div>
    ));
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form
        action="/upload"
        method="post"
        className="form"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <h3 style={{ color: "roboto, sans-serif" }}>
          Add new product to the database
        </h3>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            height: "200px",
            width: "200px",
            border: "2px solid #DADCE0",
            borderRadius: "6px",
            position: "relative",
          }}
        >
          <input
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={imageSelectedHandler}
            ref={(fileInput) => (this.fileInput = fileInput)}
            multiple={false}
            name="product_image"
          />
          <CustomButton onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()}>
            Select Image
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton onClick={imageUploadHandler}>Upload</CustomButton>

          {/*as per brad- type = "submit" value="submit"  this should not be used, file should upload with the form submit */}
          <div>
            <img
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
              }}
              alt="#"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        {createUI()}
        <div>
          <CustomButton
            onClick={addClick}
            type="button"
            style={{ margin: "14px" }}
          >
            Add More Fields
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton type="submit" style={{ margin: "12px" }}>
            Upload Product
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductUpload;
```

code with the changes suggested by @AKX

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormInput from "../Forminput/forminput";
import CustomButton from "../Custombutton/custombutton";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductUpload = () => {
  const [sub_category, setSub_category] = useState({
    sub_category: "",
  });

  const [product_name, setProduct_name] = useState({
    product_name: "",
  });

  const [product_image, setProduct_image] = useState({
    product_image: "",
  });

  const [product_specs, setProduct_specs] = useState({
    product_specs: [{ specification: "", specvalue: "" }],
  });

  const imageSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setProduct_image({ product_image: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  // const imageUploadHandler = () => {
  //   const fd = new FormData();
  //   fd.append("product_image", product_image, product_image.name); //.name is Imp as name is property of file
  // };

  const handleChange = (i, e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    product_specs[i] = { ...product_specs[i], [name]: value };
    setProduct_specs({ product_specs }); //TO BE CHECKED
  };
  //to add extra input field
  const addClick = () => {
    setProduct_specs({
      product_specs: [...product_specs, { specification: "", specvalue: "" }],
    });
  };
  //to remove extra input field
  const removeClick = (i) => {
    [product_specs].splice(i, 1);
    setProduct_specs({
      product_specs: [product_specs],
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newProduct = {
      sub_category,
      product_name,
      product_image,
      product_specs,
    };
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newProduct);
      const res = await axios.post("/api/product", body, config);
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };
  const createUI = () => {
    return [product_specs].map((el, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="inputgroup">
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="specification"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={el.specification}
          label="specification"
          required
          customwidth="300px"
        ></FormInput>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="specvalue"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={el.specvalue}
          label="specification values seperated by quomas"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        <CustomButton
          onClick={removeClick(i)}
          type="button"
          value="remove"
          style={{ margin: "12px" }}
        >
          Remove
        </CustomButton>
      </div>
    ));
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form
        action="/upload"
        method="post"
        className="form"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <h3 style={{ color: "roboto, sans-serif" }}>
          Add new product to the database
        </h3>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            height: "200px",
            width: "200px",
            border: "2px solid #DADCE0",
            borderRadius: "6px",
            position: "relative",
          }}
        >
          <input
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={imageSelectedHandler}
            ref={(fileInput) => (this.fileInput = fileInput)}
            multiple={false}
            name="product_image"
          />
          <CustomButton onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()}>
            Select Image
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton
          //  onClick={imageUploadHandler}
          >
            Upload
          </CustomButton>

          {/*as per brad- type = "submit" value="submit"  this should not be used, file should upload with the form submit */}
          <div>
            <img
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
              }}
              alt="#"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="sub_category"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={sub_category}
          label="select from subcategories"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="product_name"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={product_name}
          label="product name"
          required
        ></FormInput>
        {createUI()}
        <div>
          <CustomButton
            onClick={addClick}
            type="button"
            style={{ margin: "14px" }}
          >
            Add More Fields
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton type="submit" style={{ margin: "12px" }}>
            Upload Product
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductUpload;
```

Comment: Why all the `sub_category: { ...prevState.sub_category },` stuff? You could just spread e.g. `{...prevState, product_image: event.target.files[0],}`.

Comment: You'll also have a much better time if you split the 4 state pieces out from a single `formData` object into 4 different `useState`s.

Comment: @AKX i aprreciate your response, I have implemented the first change you sugested, I will also implement the second one, but before implementing the second one, i want my code to be error free, I am still getting same too many renders error. It will be so greatfull if you colud help me to find which part is causing that error. Thank you.

Comment: I'm quite sure you'll be able to get rid of the rerender problems doing that too.

Comment: @AKX , I have implemented the second change as well, new code is added in the above question,  but that too didn't solve the isuue, too many renders is making me bash my head. please look at the code below, if you could help. Thanks for your time. I still feel , there is some other error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I have never seen an use of `prevState` in `useState` hook like that. Basically, when you spread `prevState` it's like you saying: "keep the same values for all the state elements" then comma, then a list of new values for the state.

So, it's not necessary to re-assign the same value of `prevState` in current state (because it already have!). So, I think you should modify your code like this:

```
const imageSelectedHandler = (event) => {
  let new_product_specs = formData.product_specs;
  new_product_specs.push({ specification: "", specvalue: "" });
  setFormData((prevState) => ({
     ...prevState,
     product_image: event.target.files[0],
     product_specs: new_product_specs
   }));
};
```

For the question about `imageUploadHandler`, I don't think is required to submit form. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: HI , after your comment i tried to search on the same, some changes in the code has been made after that, thank you for the time, but the same issue persist.